# Elementary embeddings $L(\mathbb{R})\to L(\mathbb{R})$

Tags: logic, set-theory, large-cardinals

Does any known large cardinal axiom implies that there exists an elementary embedding $j:L(\mathbb{R})\to L(\mathbb{R})$ ?

Since the Axiom of Determinacy is consistent with $V=L(\mathbb{R})$ I first didn't think it was consistent with the existence of a such embedding but the usual proof that there is no embedding $j:V\to V$ relies on the Axiom of Choice which is provably false under AD so I'm not really sure.

However now I remember seeing papers about how $I0$ was an "AD-like" axiom (with $L(V_{\lambda+1})$ instead of $L(\mathbb{R})$), and $I0$ is precisely about the existence of an elementary embedding $j:L(V_{\lambda+1})\to L(V_{\lambda+1})$, so $AD^{L(\mathbb{R})}$ implying (or being implied by) the existence of an embedding $j:L(\mathbb{R})\to L(\mathbb{R})$ doesn't seem so implausible anymore.

Comment: Can you include the definition of "elementary" (embedding)  and of $L(\mathbb R)$ ?

Comment: @AymaneFihadi These are standard technical terms in logic with lengthy definitions; they don't need to be defined in the question (in the same way that we don't e.g. require questions on algebraic geometry to define "scheme").

Comment: OK, thank you @NoahSchweber. In the first glance and with the only (set-theory) tag, I thought this is fairly general mathematics.

Comment: In $\mathsf{ZF} $, if $X $ is a set and $V=L (X)$, there is no elementary embedding $j\!:L (X)\to L (X) $ (other than the identity). $\mathsf{AD}^{L (\mathbb R)}$ is compatible with $V=L (\mathbb R) $, so it cannot imply the existence of such an embedding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I might be missing something, but I think a measurable already does this. From a measurable of course we get an elementary embedding $j:V\rightarrow M$ with critical point $\kappa$. $\kappa$ is uncountable, so we have $\mathbb{R}^V=\mathbb{R}^M$; since $L$ is absolute, we further have $L(\mathbb{R})^V=L(\mathbb{R})^M$. Finally, since $L(\mathbb{R})$ is definable we know that $j$ restricts to an elementary embedding $L(\mathbb{R})\rightarrow L(\mathbb{R})$, and that this embedding is nontrivial since $\kappa\in L(\mathbb{R})$, being an ordinal.

I do not, off the top of my head, see how to get such an embedding in ZF+ V=L$(\mathbb{R})$, and I suspect that none can exist (especially if we throw AD into the mix); however, since choice fails Kunen's argument doesn't go through here, so I don't see the disproof.

Comment: A real-valued measurable suffices, even if it is one strictly below the continuum. The proof is not as immediate as for a measurable. Also, note that the existence of $\mathbb R^\sharp $  is much weaker consistencywise than a measurable: All you need are the appropriate indiscernibles. A Ramsey cardinal is more than enough, for example.

Comment: Since AC is forceable over $L(\Bbb R)$, if there was an elementary embedding, all we need to show is that its critical point is above $\Theta$ (so that we can well-order the reals and force AC with a small forcing, and thus lift the embedding). But that's easy, since a critical point of an elementary embedding must be a strongly inaccessible cardinal. Therefore there cannot be an embedding $j\colon V\to V$ under $V=L(\Bbb R)$.